# How to merge multiple Range objects, into one, for use as Chart source

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a chart, with multiple columns as source area.
Basically, I want to select specific columns, where I skip some columns, and merge them all into one range. I've setup a loop, where I create a range, and append it's address to a string, and seperates them with a comma. I'm pretty sure this is how Excel wants it formatted.

BUT, I cannot seem to create a new range from this string.

I hope someone here can help me out.

I would very much like to avoid, having to copy the columns to a new sheet, and just mark it all as a range.

I have the following code, for making the combined range:

```
'Loops for each number of sections
For Z = 1 To Sheet1.txtNoSections

    'Get gauge to use
    Section = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(26 + Z, 6).Value
    'Sets varibel for distance from root
    Dist = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(26 + Z, 3).Value
    'Get range to use
    Set ChartRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(rc, Section))
    RangeString = RangeString & ChartRange.AddressLocal
    If Z <> 1 Then
        RangeString = RangeString & ","
    End If

Next Z
```

I have then tried to get a new range with something like this, but no luck.

```
Dim ActualRange As Range
Set ActualRange = ActiveSheet.Range(RangeString)
```

When printing the RangeString, it looks like this:
`$S$2$V$6181$S$2:$X$6181,$S$2:$Z$6181,$S$2:$AB$6181,$S$2:$AD$6181,$S$2:$AF$6181,$S$2:$AH$6181,$S$2:$AJ$6181,$S$2:$AL$6181,$S$2:$AN$6181,$S$2:$AP$6181,$S$2:$AR$6181,$S$2:$AT$6181,$S$2:$AV$6181,$S$2:$AX$6181,$S$2:$AZ$6181,$S$2:$BB$6181,$S$2:$BD$6181,$S$2:$BF$6181,$S$2:$BH$6181,$S$2:$BJ$6181,$S$2:$BL$6181,$S$2:$BN$6181,$S$2:$BP$6181`

Seems like the same union would do.

Comment: You'd porbbably better use the [Union](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/16/union-and-intersect/) method than concatenating range (which won't work if your range ends with a comma `,`)

Comment: Can you post what `RangeString` looks like after you run the code? You can put a `Debug.Print RangeString` after `Next Z` and check it's value. edit: Good point Jmax :)

Comment: @JMax, Of course my string ended on a comma. I've changed it, but it still fails when I try to set the range.

Comment: missing a comma in `$S$2$V$6181$S$2:$X$6181` Also if you consider `$S$2:$X$6181,$S$2:$Z$6181` then it doesn't make sense as S-Z will include S-X and so on for the rest

Comment: I believe this is what you are trying? `RangeString` should look like this `"S2:S6181,V2:V6181,X2:X6181,Z2:Z14,AB1:AB6181,........,BP2:BP6181"`

Comment: Your RangeString is missing a first comma to delimit the first Range. You **really** should use standard functions such as Union

Comment: Yea, I can see that I've kinda skipped the first comma :). @JMax, you are right. I should use standard functions. I did not know about union, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JMax, Union was the way to go :). If you make an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the best way to handle this is to use native VBA functions such as `Union`.

You can find several references on how to use this:

- on [Daily dose of Excel](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/16/union-and-intersect/)
- on [vba Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=354)
- even a "better" Union on [Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/BetterUnion.aspx)

Yet, please note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and the way you've solved your issue with your own code.
IMHO, this would be even better than accepting my answer.

Comment: I've replied with the code I ended up with. I really don't want to mark my own answer, when you solved my problem :).

Answer (score 2):

Following JMax's guidance, I ended up using Union.
This is the code I ended up with.
The first time through the loop, I set the CombinedRange to my actual range, and the subsequent runs, I union.

```
For Z = 1 To Sheet1.txtNoSections

    'Get gauge to use
    Section = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(26 + Z, 6).Value
    'Get range to use
    Set ChartRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(rc, 0))
    Debug.Print "ChartRange(" & Z & "): " & ChartRange.Address
    If Z = 1 Then
        Set CombinedRange = ChartRange
    Else
        Set CombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, ChartRange)
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Activate

Next Z
Debug.Print "Combined: " & CombinedRange.Address
```