# excel vba set one range object by other two range object

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my problem. I have two Range Object. For example,

```
    Set rg3 = Range("B2")
    Set rg4 = Range("B3000")
```

I want to do this

```
    Range("rg3:rg4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

But it show error. How can I select the region by two range object. 
Range("B2:B3000") is not correct in my case because those two range would always updated by offset function.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean by 'those two range would always be updated by offset function'? Otherwise you can try: `Range(rg3.Address & ":" & rg4.Address).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)` but I think you are saying that isn't what you want.

Comment: Try the union function, as in [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9903792/1490783).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter `Range(` the intellisense will show `Range(Cell1, Cell2) as Range` indicating the the Range object is expecting two cells.

So, seeing as rg3 and rg4 are two cells you can use `Range(rg3, rg4)`.

You're using `xlPasteAll` so you could just use `RangeBeingCopiedReference.Copy Destination:=Range(rg3,rg4)`

Edit - and as @Robin says, what do you mean by the offsetting?

Edit 2:
If you want to loop through a range then using `Cells` is easier as it accepts a column number rather than a column letter.

This example will copy columns A:J over to U:AD one column at a time.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rg3 As Range, rg4 As Range
    Dim x As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 1 To 10
            .Range(.Cells(2, x), .Cells(3000, x)).Copy _
                Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, x + 20), .Cells(3000, x + 20))
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Also - look up reference on `WITH... END WITH` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx

Comment: rg3 and rg4 is inside a for loop, each time it will move to next colmn by offset(0, 1)

Comment: You may be better using `Cells` rather than `Range` if you want to increase your range reference in a loop.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to better understand your needs for better help

as a start, since your using of `.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` I'd believe you're setting a source range outside a loop and paste it multiple times inside this latter shifting pasting range

you also explained *"rg3 and rg4 is inside a for loop, each time it will move to next colmn by offset(0, 1)"*

so this would initially lead to:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim copyRng As Range, rg3 As Range, rg4 As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rg3 = Range("B2") '<~~ your rg3 range setting
    Set rg4 = Range("B3000") '<~~ your rg4 range setting
    Set copyRng = ... '<~~ your setting of the "source" range to be copied once and pasted many
    copyRng.Copy '<~~ copy "source" Range once ...
    With Range(rg3, rg4) '<~~ ... set your initial "target" range ...
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Offset(, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll '<~~ ... and paste "source" range offseting "target" once
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

but this would also be uselessly long and slow, since you could simply write:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim copyRng As Range, rg3 As Range

    Set rg3 = Range("B2") '<~~ just set the "beginning" of the target range
    Set copyRng = ... '<~~ your setting of the "source" range to be copied once and pasted many
    copyRng.Copy copyRng.Copy Destination:=rg3.Resize(, 10)   
End Sub
```

so what's your real need?